# Extract numbers from excel cell with mixed text

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I am trying to create a function to extract numbers from a excel cell text and apply some logic to the number. I have gone through a lot of youtube videos and google article to extract these details but none of them are working for my case.

**Problem: Excel cell contain "Tax (15%)", now i want to extract 15 and be able to perform some operations on it. The number could be 1/2/3 digit Tax.**

I tried all formulas found in article and going through youtube videos:

```
=VALUE(MID(B10,row(INDIRECT("1:"&len(B10))),1))
```

```
=TEXTJOIN("", TRUE, IF(ISNUMBER(--MID(A1, ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))), 1)), MID(A1, ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))), 1), ""))
```

these are not working.

I need a formula which works for all versions of excel(2007 and above) and works on google sheet and doc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Btw, there's no guarantee that the same formula with satisfy all your requirements (Excel, Google Sheets).

Comment: If you want to do this for "any" calculation program you only can work with regular expressions from outside, f.e. with python. As far as I know excel doesn't support regexes in formulas, but in VBA. about google and so on I do not know anything. And it would be interesting, if the content is ever that easy - any NOT- Numbers, a Bracket, numbers (maybe with dot or komma) followed by percent- sign and the other bracket and nothing more. That would be not too difficult ...

Answer (score 2):

Found a way to search between two character ( "(" and "%" in my case) did the trick.

```
=MID(A1, SEARCH("(", A1) + 1, SEARCH("%", A1) - SEARCH("(", A1) - 1)
```

Comment: Nice solution. If you add `--` in front of MID the string becomes a true number.

Answer (score 0):

`=MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(ROW($1:$1000)-1,A1)),ROW($1:$1000)-1,))`
This also works if other, or no characters would be used.

Note that this would return `0` in case no number is in the cell's content.

Comment: Sir, `AGGREGATE()` is not available in `Excel 2007` it is from `Excel 2010` instead you can replace `AGGREGATE()` with `IF()` and `SMALL()`

Comment: I could've sworn Excel 2010 was tagged. Changed it back to my initial thought. I used AGGREGATE to deal with the case no number would be in the cell to not show `0` as a result.

Comment: Yes OP tagged `Google-Docs` as well. But wrote in the main OP Excel 2007 onwards

Answer (score 0):

For Excel and in the case, that there is only one bracket ( and one %- sign, you could use

```
=VALUE(MID(B10,SEARCH("(",B10)+1,SEARCH("%",B10)-SEARCH("(",B10)-1))
```

But I can not imagine, that this is that easy.

If you use regular expressions, f.e. via python, you could do something like that:

```
import re

text = 'Tax (15%)'

pattern = re.compile(r'.*'
    '[(](?P<TAX>\d+)%[)]'
    '.*')

m = pattern.match(text)
if m:
    tax = int(m.groupdict()['TAX'])
    print (tax)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following formula works on my end in both the platforms i.e. **`Excel`** as **`Google-Sheets`**

In `Excel`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=REPLACE(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1),1,FIND("(",A1),)*100
```

---

In `Google-Sheets`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=REPLACE(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1),1,FIND("(",A1),)*100
```

---